# Problem when installing google-cloud-speech python API in raspberry pi 3 (Jessie) via pip

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to install the google-cloud-speech python API for raspberry pi 3 (raspbian Jessie) using pip (1.5.6). I follow the instructions given by:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#client-libraries-install-python

but when installing the library using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

I get this error:

```
error in grpcio setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
```

and the installation doesn't finish. The same job worked for me some months ago, so I guess some changes was made. Any ideas?

I've already tried upgrading pip

Comment: Your `pip` version is very old.

Answer (score 0):

Start with upgrading installation tools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your setup tools/ pip

```
pip install setuptools -U
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all! now it is working. I'm pretty sure I tried before one of:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
pip install setuptools -U
```

But the thing is that executing both of them the installation finished correctly.